# Как от числа х отсоединить часть после запятой?

Tags: python

Как от числа х отсоединить часть после запятой.
Мы получаем число на ввод. Например, 123.45. Как оставить только 0.45?

Это просто пример. Может быть  и число 123.45678

Comment: Читать дубликат то тех пор пока не поймёте что числа `123.45` тоже нет.

Comment: Ну а если я хочу получить число после запятой, чтобы его можно было умножить на 10-100-1000 и тп. от разряда, чтобы получить целое? как я могу, к примеру, 0.45000000000000284 умножать на 10-100-1000? Мне нужно, чтобы было 0.45

Comment: Странные люди, которые минусуют.  Неужели мой вопрос не "отражает мое стремление разобраться?". Я очень хочу разобраться. Что за глупости?

Answer (score 0):

print(round(a-b,3))  может так?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: а если вы не знаете, до какого числа округлять? если, например, x = 123.45678